# How can you create a function with same shape that the cosine function but with thorns?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

While I was playing with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com), I've found what seems an exceptional recreation. Create a function with the same shape of a cosine function, more or less the same shape, but with thorns. I call to a function of such kind a cactus-cosine.

Variants of my example

$$ \left\{ x \right\}^{ \left\{ x \right\} }\cos(x), $$ where $ \left\{ x \right\} $ is the fractional part function, that I believe that aren't periodic functions, are written in Wolfram Language as

`plot frac(x)^frac(x)cos(x/2), for 0<x<50`

or

`plot frac(x)^frac(x)cos(x/4), for 0<x<50`

I would like to know new expressions or methods to obtain a similar result. Isn't required that yourself method to draw a cactus-cosine will provide us  periodic functions, only is required that seems periodic more or less and with the same shape of a cosine. But it is required that you use the cosine function in your expression, formula or recurrence, to avoid simple answers based in fractals of triangles.

> **Question.** Can you make a different cosine with thorns in a segment using in your expression, formula or recurrence at least a cosine function? Isn't required that it be a periodic function, but it is required that it has more or less the shape of a cosine function. You can do sum, multiply,..composition with special functions, to create your function, recurrence... **Many thanks.**

Comment: How is $\{x\}$ not periodic?

Comment: My plots don't seems periodic, I say the plot for $\left\{ x \right\}^{ \left\{ x \right\} }\cos(x)$. Many thanks @KennyLau

Comment: @user243301 $\{x\}^{\{x\}}\cos x$ is not periodic because $\{x\}^{\{x\}}$ is periodic of period 1 while $\cos x$ is periodic of period $2 \pi$. The product of two periodic functions of incommensurable periods is not periodic (Think to its fourier decomposition)

Comment: @user243301 $\{x\}^{\{x\}}\cos \frac{2\pi}{50}x$ is, for instance, periodic of period $50$. plot frac(x)^frac(x) cos(2 pi /50 x), for 0<x<50

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation @trying and also to the other user. Many thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: http://www.calpoly.edu/~fowen/me318/FourierSeriesTable.pdf

Comment: @user243301 Try [$1/2 - \sqrt{1-|cos(x)|}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2+-+sqrt(1-%7Ccos(x)%7C)). It is periodic, and quite pointy.

Comment: Many thnaks @dxiv

Comment: Many thanks @reuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create thorns is with absolute value of a periodic function, such as cosine. Such a "thorns" function can be $$\frac{1}{|\cos x|+1}$$ I did not want my thorns to be divergent. If that's not a problem, use $|\cos x|^{-1}$. You can change periodicity of the thorns by multiplying $x$ by a factor, and amplitude of the thorns by multiplying the whole expression by a constant. Now, to apply it on top of the cosine function, you can add (thorns will point always up), subtract (thorns will point down), or multiply (thorns will point away from the axis)

```
plot ((1/(abs(cos(x*5))+1)+cos(x/2)), for 0<x<50
plot ((-1/(abs(cos(x*5))+1)+cos(x/2)), for 0<x<50
plot ((1/(abs(cos(x*5))+1)*cos(x/2)), for 0<x<50
```

Comment: Many thanks for your example and for the explanation of your technique to create thorns, it is nice.